# Why filename is not getting rendered properly

Tags: tcl

I am in need to redirect output of program to a file and below is the code that I am using to create the output log file name:

```
set filename "C:\tools\tcl\bin\my.log"
puts "The log file $filename"
```

But this prints :

```
 The log file C: ools    cinmy.log
```

Note I can also receive the filename as argument to script:

```
set logfile [lindex $argv 1]
```

How can I resolve the issue for both case when receive logfile as arg and as constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tcl` will do [backslash substitution](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16) and these substitution will happen only with double quotes. If you need a literal backslash, you have to escape it. When enclosed with braces, these substitution will not happen.

So, you can define your variable as

```
set filename "C:\\tools\\tcl\\bin\\my.log"
```

or

```
set filename {C:\tools\tcl\bin\my.log}
```

About the command line argument stuff, don't bother. `Tcl` will take care of it. It will be received as it is from your terminal.

Comment: Thanks but I have a scenario where I have to make use of file name as provided in command line like set filename {$argv[1]} - I mean how can I use variables in {} when it is a filename. The values might not only be received from command line arguments but also from INI file opened for reading config

Comment: If you are simply reading the contents of a file and assigning it into a variable, then these escape sequence will not impact your code. This is applied only when you define a variable in your code.

Comment: Ok I think the issue in printing the config variable using puts - probably the substiuon is taking place - how can I escape print a variable which as '\' but is not a constant?

Answer (score 0):

> But this prints :
>
> `The log file C: ools    cinmy.log`

This is because a literal string between double quotes is subjected to backslash substitution. For example, `"\t"` is interpreted as the tab control character, and not as a file-path element with `\` as separator.

Your options:

- Escape the single backslashes: `"\t"` becomes `"\\t"`
- Use curly braces, which prevents backslash substitution from happening: `"\t"` becomes `{\t}`
- Use Tcl's [`[file]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm) command to assemble the file path:

  `file nativename [file join C:/ tools tcl bin my.log]`

The latter option is the preferred one.

Comment: Thanks - but if we are receiving the values by reading a config / INI file? How can we set the same if its value is c:\tools\tcl\...

Comment: As Dinesh wrote, Tcl will preserve the filepaths as obtained from the command line (`[lindex $args 1]`) or the config file. You don't have to worry about backslash substitution in this case.

Comment: Ok I think the issue in printing the config variable using puts - probably the substiuon is taking place - how can I escape print a variable which as '\' but is not a constant?

Comment: No, `puts` is not triggering backslash substitution. Watch for yourself: `set x {\t}; puts $x; puts [subst $x]`. The [`[subst]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm) command is required to request substitution. I suspect the way you obtain the filepaths from your config file is causing eager substitution. You will have to show code.

Comment: I am trying this way - set f "C:\tools\tcl\bin\my.log" ; puts "$f";

Comment: Then you missed the whole point of our answers :) Make this: `set f {C:\tools\tcl\bin\my.log} ; puts $f`

Comment: The point is that even if we read from config / command line arguments printing them causes problem leading to idea that its value is corrupt?

Comment: Then you have to show how *exactly* your read from conf/ command line. Not just smoke-test code.