# Why the filename is not getting printed correctly

Tags: tcl

I am trying to print a filename with its complete path using below code. As per code implementation I find the ASCII value of each character of string and check if its ASCII value is that of '\' (backslash) character - then print accordingly:

```
set f "C:\tools\tcl\bin\my.log"
for {set i 0} {$i < [string length $f]} {incr i} {
   set c [scan [string index $f $i] %c]
   if { $c == 9 } {
       puts -nonewline "\\"
   } else {
      puts -nonewline [string index $f $i]
   }
}
```

But I am getting below output:

```
C:\ools\cinmy.log
```

Please let me know how can I fix the same?

My question is said to be duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603435/why-filename-is-not-getting-rendered-properly) but is actually not. In that question it is printing as string within double quotes but here I am printing it character by character

Comment: My question is not duplicate of another question In that question it is printing as string within double quotes but here I am printing it character by character

Comment: It seems to be quite related: In your code, when you encounter a `9` you replace it by a `\ ` .... But `9` is the ascii code of **TAB** character. Did you notice that neither `\b` nor `\m` are displayed?

Comment: It's exactly a duplicate of that question; if you're using backslashes in filenames, _put them in `{`braces`}`_ or the string will be mangled. (`\b` becomes the backspace character, for example, which is why the `l` of `cl\bin` seemingly goes missing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are escaping the characters after the backslash (`\`) ([backslash substitution](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16)). 
You should use double backslash (`\\`) or braces to define the file.

In summary, you need to define the file as:

`set f "C:\\tools\\tcl\\bin\\my.log"`

or

`set f {C:\tools\tcl\bin\my.log}`